# How to send data from NodeJS to React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

This is the code of mine where it consist of Js File and React File.

```
//
// JS File 
//
...
app.post('/searchResult',function(req,res)
{
res.send(searchValue);
console.log(`----------------------------`);
console.log(`Search Result :`+ searchValue);
})
...
//
// React File
//
...
axios.post(BASE_URL + '/searchResult')
.then(res => 
{
dataResult = res;
console.log(`The result :`+ dataResult);
})
...
//
//
//
```

The Result : [object Object]

Any solutions ?

Comment: in your api return json.... like this  return res.json(searchValue)

Comment: In your react app, try to console.log(res.data)

Comment: @sathishkumar,  I put like this, and the result is still [object Object]

app.post('/searchResult',function(req,res)

   {

   res.send(searchValue);

   console.log(`----------------------------`);

   console.log(`Search Result :`+ searchValue);   
   res.json(searchValue)
   })

Comment: @Israelkusayev I try to console.log(res.data) and it shows nothing tho. does this mean it does not manage to pass the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at response it contains a lot of stuff along with the data you have sent from your api endpoint as a response which comes to you in the nested object format. So you need to specify which part of the response you want to access.
Try using the following:

```
dataResult = res.data;
OR
dataResult = res.body;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I try both res.data and res.body. The result for both is still the same which is  [object Object]

Comment: wrap it up in JSON.stringify. Like this JSON.stringify(res.data)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the response this should work:

```
    axios.post(BASE_URL + '/searchResult').then(({data}) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

and if you are returning data as a string try:

```
const result = JSON.parse(data);
```